# JBoss EAP 6.1 Oracle ADF 11

Tags: jsf, jboss, oracle-adf

I'm trying to migrate JBoss EAP 5.1 application to JBoss EAP 6.1.
My app uses JSF 1.2, MyFaces Trinidad and Oracle ADF 11 as jsf component libraries.

The app was working fine on JBoss EAP 5.1.

The deployment on JBoss EAP 6.1 is fine, but it seems that adf components seems are causing problems.
The application generates exception when trying to open a page that uses ADF components.
Here is the full stack trace:

```
    Failed to define class oracle.jbo.domain.Number in Module "deployment.MyAppServer.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link oracle/jbo/domain/Number (Module "deployment.MyAppServer.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:427) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:260) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:75) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:526) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:188) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:444) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:432) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:374) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:119) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.rich.marshal.DefaultMarshalingService._registerDefaults(DefaultMarshalingService.java:244) [adf-richclient-impl-11.jar:]
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.rich.marshal.DefaultMarshalingService.<init>(DefaultMarshalingService.java:73) [adf-richclient-impl-11.jar:]
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.rich.marshal.DefaultMarshalingService.<clinit>(DefaultMarshalingService.java:334) [adf-richclient-impl-11.jar:]
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.event.rich.ClientEventUtils._getEventParameters(ClientEventUtils.java:248) [adf-richclient-impl-11.jar:]
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.event.rich.ClientEventUtils._parseEvents(ClientEventUtils.java:177) [adf-richclient-impl-11.jar:]
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.event.rich.ClientEventUtils._getAndLoadEvents(ClientEventUtils.java:146) [adf-richclient-impl-11.jar:]
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.event.rich.ClientEventUtils.decodeAndStoreClientEvents(ClientEventUtils.java:125) [adf-richclient-impl-11.jar:]
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.context.RichPhaseListener.beforePhase(RichPhaseListener.java:249) [adf-richclient-impl-11.jar:]
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:258) [adf-richclient-impl-11.jar:]
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:177) [adf-richclient-impl-11.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265) [jsf-api-1.2_15-b01-redhat-3.jar:1.2_15-b01-redhat-3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:97) [adf-richclient-impl-11.jar:]
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:420) [trinidad-impl-1.2.12.1.jar:1.2.12.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60) [adf-richclient-impl-11.jar:]
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:420) [trinidad-impl-1.2.12.1.jar:1.2.12.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:247) [trinidad-impl-1.2.12.1.jar:1.2.12.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:157) [trinidad-impl-1.2.12.1.jar:1.2.12.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92) [trinidad-api-1.2.12.1.jar:1.2.12.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83) [jboss-seam-2.2.2.EAP5.jar:2.2.2.EAP5]
    at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60) [jboss-seam-2.2.2.EAP5.jar:2.2.2.EAP5]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam-2.2.2.EAP5.jar:2.2.2.EAP5]
    at com.edf.marketlab.web.filter.SessionActivityFilter.doFilter(SessionActivityFilter.java:67) [classes:]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam-2.2.2.EAP5.jar:2.2.2.EAP5]
    at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40) [jboss-seam-2.2.2.EAP5.jar:2.2.2.EAP5]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam-2.2.2.EAP5.jar:2.2.2.EAP5]
    at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90) [jboss-seam-2.2.2.EAP5.jar:2.2.2.EAP5]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam-2.2.2.EAP5.jar:2.2.2.EAP5]
    at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64) [jboss-seam-2.2.2.EAP5.jar:2.2.2.EAP5]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam-2.2.2.EAP5.jar:2.2.2.EAP5]
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45) [jboss-seam-2.2.2.EAP5.jar:2.2.2.EAP5]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam-2.2.2.EAP5.jar:2.2.2.EAP5]
    at org.jboss.seam.web.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:42) [jboss-seam-2.2.2.EAP5.jar:2.2.2.EAP5]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam-2.2.2.EAP5.jar:2.2.2.EAP5]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158) [jboss-seam-2.2.2.EAP5.jar:2.2.2.EAP5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:389) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/sql/ORAData
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:344) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:422) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 60 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.sql.ORAData from [Module "deployment.MyAppServer.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:196) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:444) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:432) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:374) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:119) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
```

I'm using the default JSF implementation (Mojorra) provided by JBoss.

Here is my jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="main" />
            <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="main" />
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="1.2" />
            <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="1.2" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Here is my pom.xml with the ADF dependencies :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.adf</groupId>
        <artifactId>adfm</artifactId>
        <version>11.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>
            ${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/adfm.jar
        </systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.adf</groupId>
        <artifactId>adf-richclient-api</artifactId>
        <version>11.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>
            ${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/adf-richclient-api-11.jar
        </systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.adf</groupId>
        <artifactId>adf-richclient-impl</artifactId>
        <version>11.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>
            ${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/adf-richclient-impl-11.jar
        </systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.adf</groupId>
        <artifactId>adflogginghandler</artifactId>
        <version>11.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>
            ${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/adflogginghandler.jar
        </systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.adf</groupId>
        <artifactId>adf-share-base</artifactId>
        <version>11.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>
            ${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/adf-share-base.jar
        </systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.adf</groupId>
        <artifactId>adf-share-ca</artifactId>
        <version>11.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>
            ${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/adf-share-ca.jar
        </systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.adf</groupId>
        <artifactId>adf-share-support</artifactId>
        <version>11.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>
            ${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/adf-share-support.jar
        </systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.adf</groupId>
        <artifactId>dms</artifactId>
        <version>11.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>
            ${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/dms.jar
        </systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.adf</groupId>
        <artifactId>mdsrt</artifactId>
        <version>11.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>
            ${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/mdsrt.jar
        </systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.adf</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlparserv2-distilled-9i</artifactId>
        <version>11.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>
            ${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/xmlparserv2-distilled-9i.jar
        </systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad</groupId>
        <artifactId>trinidad-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.12.1</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>
            ${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/trinidad-api-1.2.12.1.jar
        </systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad</groupId>
        <artifactId>trinidad-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.12.1</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>
            ${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/trinidad-impl-1.2.12.1.jar
        </systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: The stack traces all point to missing JARs in your WAR.  How are you including the ADF runtime in your WAR?

Comment: All jars added are defined in my pom.xml (see my edit).  I opened my war to check and all jars are inside in the right place.

Comment: This is your error line: `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/sql/ORAData` if that's coming from the ojdbc driver, you need to add the driver to dependencies in `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`

Comment: Allright I see, it seems strange to have to put this ojdbc driver as I do not make any connection to oracle database and do not even have one oracle database.  But I've added it and I don't have this exception anymore.  Thank you.